# Is there any API to get global current time

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3, geocoding

In my app I want to set current time.I know we can get it via device but it became user specific. If user change his device time then i am not able to find current time in my report.So is there any API which can give me current time based on location or LAT-LONG.
Please share if any one has idea about this.
Thanks All.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WorldTimeEngine webservice](http://worldtimeengine.com/api/geo) offers an API that converst geolocation coordinates into local time.

Edit: there's this [AskGeo web API](http://askgeo.com/) also, it seems to be free and provide time information.

Comment: can we find this functionality in google api or other free api?

Comment: @sinh99 I believe no, but I may know it correctly Anyway, this was among the first hits on Google and it doesn't require Google's ugly data APIs :)